# Rocket League local multiplayer via steam link + DS4 controllers

Tags: steam, controllers, rocket-league, steam-link

I would like to play a Rocket League local co-op game on my TV via a Steam Link with 2 players DS4 controllers.

When I launch the game, the keyboard and mouse work, and one of the controllers works, but both seem to be tied to player one. Pressing the option button on any further DS4 controllers has no effect, and because the game doesn't detect the additional controllers I can't start local co-op games.

The two DS4 controllers are paired with the Steam Link device - my PC is in another room - and I am using Big Picture mode.

I've tried using x360ce to force one of the controllers to be assigned to player 2, as specified in [this post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/252950/discussions/3/1457328392112649636/?ctp=2#c2579854400744677127), but that doesn't seem to have worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried [DS4Windows](https://ryochan7.github.io/ds4windows-site/) for treating the DS4 controllers as Xbox 360?

Comment: @Lemon Not yet - thank you for the suggestion.